# Is it possible to connect a Nintendo Switch directly to a monitor without the dock?

Tags: nintendo-switch, hardware

As the title says - is it possible to connect Nintendo Switch directly, without a dock station, to the screen?

I noticed that I often do something on PC and in the meantime play on undocked Switch. It will be cool if I could just plug some screen into the Switch by HDMI/DP to USB-C adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you will need a USB-C to HDMI adapter (random one off Amazon [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BVHSNF3G)).  Once you have one, it  should be possible.

There is a video here explaining how to set it up:

Also a guide can be found [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/connect-nintendo-switch-to-tv-without-dock/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Connect%20Nintendo%20Switch,a%20single%20USB%2DC%20output.).

Basically, you connect the USB-C power cable and HDMI cable from the dock (or whatever HDMI cable you have connected to your display) to your adapter, and then you plug the adapter into your Switch.  You can think of the adapter as the new "dock". All the controllers and such should still work even:

> You can use the Joy-Cons individually, connected to the Joy-Con Grip, or use a Switch Pro Controller, just as you would normally. There should be absolutely no difference to the experience, other than the absence of the Nintendo Switch dock.

Comment: Ah, it seems that HDMI must be keyword. I tried to do it by display port cable and display port to usb-c adapter, and it didn't work.

Comment: @TravelerVihaan I see - not sure how that would work since I think the Switch only supports HDMI.

Comment: Note that not all USB-C to HDMI adapter work. I do have some for my Mac that doesn't work with the switch, so it's better to purchase one that is known to work correctly.

Comment: @JFL, you're right. I bought adapter, but it works only with devices which handle protocol MHL. So, it seems that Nintendo Switch does not belong to this group of devices, because adapter does not work. I think it's important in case of my question.